# Should I free the C array I pass into NSBezierPath's setLineDash:count:phase: method?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsbezierpath

I am setting the line dash style on an NSBezierPath instance:

```
NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath path];
// Get the path information...

NSInteger count = 0;
// Get the array count...

CGFloat *dashLengths = (CGFloat *)malloc(sizeof(CGFloat) * count);
// Populate the array...

CGFloat phase = 0.0f;
// Get the phase...

[path setLineDash:dashLengths count:count phase:phase];
```

Should I call free() on dashLengths to prevent a memory leak? Or would releasing the array cause a error later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `malloc` in the first place? Just declare

```
CGFloat dashLengths[count];
```

Now `dashLengths` is an automatic variable. No memory management required.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot you could make C arrays this way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must `free()` that `malloc()`'d array yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should call free() on dashLengths right after you free path. NSBezierPath has no way of retaining it, since it's just a regular ol pointer, so you should not take that memory away until NSBezierPath goes away.